# How can I use a filename with special characters in a Content-Disposition header?

Tags: php, http-headers

I have a problem with some php code:

```
$link = $_GET['url'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$str = '[wanted-web.ro]';

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$str $name");
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg;\r\n");
readfile(str_replace(' ', '_', $link));
```

That is the code I use to save files.
When I want to download some direct files to my computer, that dot what I use in **wanted-web.ro** stop writing the rest of information after dot "**.**", such like this:

**[wanted-web**

Problem SOLVED!

Thank you verry much to all. You are awesome. I combined your comments, and the result is:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"[wanted-web.ro] $name.mp3\"");
```

That work perfect! Thanks very much to all. Respect!

Comment: Do you actually want the file name on disk to have `[]`s?

Comment: That looks like it's stopping after the `-`, not after the `.`.

Comment: i want to be saved like <b>[wanted-web.ro] Rest of information</b>  .. But show only <b>[wanted</b> when i want to save the file in my computer

Comment: What operating system? Not all OSes allow `[` or `]` in file names; this may not be an issue with your code but a limitation of the OS.

Comment: Expanding on @MattBall's comment, I'd guess it's extremely likely that `'[wanted-web.ro]'` should be `'wanted-web.ro'` instead. `filename=` refers to the suggested file for the user when they're downloading it to their hard drive. Could you explain a little more about your end goal?

Comment: So.. I have a grabber script. That script allow people to search music.mp3 from internet .. So, i have a search box, and a result page.. When i search some mp3 files, show me the result to another page.. When i click desired link to download some file.mp3 , show me a prompt box with "Save As: Filename" in my case "[www.wanted-web.ro] Filename .. But show me only "[wanted" not "[wanted-web.ro] Filename"  .. That problem is caused by that dot used in "[wanted-web.ro"   ... Sorry for my bad english, hope to understand something :)

Comment: Try it with this test filename to see if this is what you want: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"wanted-web.ro.mp3\"");`

Answer (score 4):

Quote the filename in the header:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$str $name\"");
```

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6266.txt

Comment: thank you for your comment, but same problem.. Doesn't show the rest of information after dot

Comment: Thank you verry much to all.. You are awesome.. I combined your comments, and the result is:  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"[wanted-web.ro] $name.mp3\"");   ..That work perfect !! Thanks verry much to all. Respect!

Comment: Cool...I'd still recommend not using the [ ] brackets...you don't know what weird issues that might cause on some devices. Probably wouldn't matter much but consider using dashes or underscores instead.

Comment: Ok Matt .. Thank you verry much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$link = $_GET['url'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$str = "[wanted-web.ro]";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$str." ".$name);
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg;\r\n");
readfile(str_replace(' ', '_', $link));
```

Comment: Same... Show me only [wanted-web   ..The rest disapear. I dont know what to do.. I spend 5 hours to resolve that problem, but in vain :(

Comment: Try it without the [ and ], maybe those are causing an issue somehow, and as already pointed out, could be problematic depending on the user's operating system. Better to stick with just letters, numbers, dashes, dots, and underscores for filenames.

Comment: Also I don't think the `$name` is doing anything here since it's after a space; @MattBall's answer is better.

Comment: I've tryed without "[ ]" but same problem !!

Comment: Try this test script instead and maybe it will get you on the right track: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"wanted-web.ro.mp3\"");
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg;\r\n");
echo 'mp3 data here';`

(Yes, you can actually use that echo 'mp3 data here' line and it will work to download a file even though it obviously won't be a real MP3; this is just a test anyway.)

Comment: Thank you verry much to all.. You are awesome.. I combined your comments, and the result is: header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"[wanted-web.ro] $name.mp3\""); ..That work perfect !! Thanks verry much to all. Respect!